# Puppet: install Rubygem-package on a machine without Rubygems preinstalled

Tags: rubygems, configuration-management, puppet

On a clean Debian system - without Rubygems installed - I want to install a Rubygem package with Puppet (Version 2.7.13). So the package has "gem" as package Provider.

This is my manifest so far (I kept it simple):

```
# test.pp
Package { ensure => 'installed' } 

package { 
  'rubygems' : 
    name => 'rubygems',
}

package {
  'libldap-ruby1.8' :
    name => 'libldap-ruby1.8',
}

package { 'libldap2-dev' : 
   name => 'libldap2-dev', 
}

package { 'libsasl2-dev' : 
  name => 'libsasl2-dev', 
}

package { 'libsasl2-modules-ldap' : 
  name => 'libsasl2-modules-ldap', 
}

# My Rubygem, with Provider type 'gem'
package { 
  'ruby-ldap' : 
    name => 'ruby-ldap',
    provider => 'gem',
}

Package [ 'rubygems' ] -> Package [ 'ruby-ldap' ] 
Package [ 'libldap2-dev' ] -> Package [ 'ruby-ldap' ]
Package [ 'libsasl2-modules-ldap' ] -> Package [ 'ruby-ldap' ]
```

When I test this manifest (with `puppet apply --noop test.pp`), I'm getting the following output:

```
err: /Stage[main]//Package[ruby-ldap]: Provider gem is not functional on this host
```

I digged through the net and found some informations about Puppet+Rubygems (for example [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/puppet-users/7DdudbY90cY)) but none of these helped me to solve my problem as none provided a real solution with some code.

I also tried using classes and stages (doing the rubygem install in a stage before the gem install) but I always got the `Provider gem`-error (but maybe I just used the stages in a wrong way).

Can anyone provide me a working manifest which installs rubygems and any rubygem on a system without Rubygems, or at least the final hints how to get there?

Comment: I found out that I can use ruby-ldap just by installing the package libldap-ruby and so I don't need to install any gems. Still I would like to know how to install Rubygems with Puppet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although my problem should be fixed with Puppet 2.7.8 (I was using 2.7.13) - see [this issue](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/6907) - I'm quite sure that I had this problem with 2.7.13.

I re-tried this on another machine with 2.7.14 installed, there I can succesfully install Rubygems and a Rubygem-package with Puppet.